# Using Emma without instrumenting src folder

Tags: emma

I am using Emma for the first time and would like to know if there is any way of instrumenting this tool with only .jar files because I have no access to the original source code.

how can .jar be instrumented from commandline and through ANT script as well?

-Thanks!